# C++ string split error (the complex way)

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, boost, split

I am trying to spit a string in C++ with the following way:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>

using namespace std;
size_t const N = 10000000;

typedef string::const_iterator iter;
typedef boost::iterator_range<iter> string_view;

template<typename C>
void test_custom(string const& s, char const* d, C& ret)
{
    C output;

    bitset<255> delims;
    while (*d)
    {
        unsigned char code = *d++;
        delims[code] = true;
    }
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;
    iter beg;
    bool in_token = false;

    bool go = false;

    for (string::const_iterator it = s.begin(), end = s.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (delims[*it])
        {
            if (in_token)
            {

                output.push_back(typename C::value_type(beg, it));
                in_token = false;
            }
        }
        else if (!in_token)
        {
            beg = it;
            in_token = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!go)
            {
                cout << typename C::value_type(beg, it);
                //outputs the first character
                go = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (in_token)
        output.push_back(typename C::value_type(beg, s.end()));
    output.swap(ret);
}

vector<string_view> split_string(string in, const char* delim = " ")
{
    vector<string_view> vsv;
    test_custom(in, delim, vsv);

    return vsv;
}

int split()
{
    string text = "123 456";

    vector<string_view> vsv = split_string(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < vsv.size(); i++)
        cout << endl << vsv.at(i) << "|" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is the fact that the first character is erased for one reason... The returned string are **' 23'** and '456' but I want them to be **'123'** and '456'

So, the first character is ' ' and not '1'

Comment: I tried my best but I can't get it to work... I have a `cout` in my code; there the first character is on `typename C::value_type(beg, it)`, but I can't put this in the `output`

Comment: The first caharcter is ' ' and not '1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `boost::iterator_range`, but it sure sounds like a pair of iterators.

If so, then in this code:

```
vector<string_view> split_string(string in, const char* delim = " ")
{
    vector<string_view> vsv;
    test_custom(in, delim, vsv);

    return vsv;
}
```

you're returning iterators referring to a local `string` called `in`, that has ceased to exist when the function returns.

That's Undefined Behavior.

One fix would be to pass that string by reference.

---

By the way, one inefficient but simple and safe way to split a string on whitespace is to use a `istringstream`:

```
istringstream stream( source_string );
string word;
while( stream >> word ) { cout << word; }
```

Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using Boost, you could use this (the "simple" way :P):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string text = "this is sample string";
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
boost::split(tokens, text, boost::is_any_of("\t "));
```

Or use whatever separator(s) you want to use as third argument.